Amcl failure with nav2 tutorial
I've been messing around with nav2 lately and i tried some of the tutorials (more specificaly https://docs.nav2.org/tutorials/docs/navigation2_on_real_turtlebot3.html). It's a straight up tutorial and i got it working but something weird is happening. As you can see in the video, when i try to move the robot, it quickly loses orientation and starts to twitch. I thought it was odometry, but when i checked it, it works fine and is really accurate. Also my lidar is giving good scan. It must be amcl that is failing. Any thought, has anyone been in the same situation?
Update:
To fix this I modified update_min_a and update_min_d params of the amcl node and set them to a smaller value.
